# How to create a Singleton in c++winrt

Tags: c++-winrt

How can we create a single tone class in c++/winrt?

I have done this in c++/cx. Why not working on c++.winrt?

How I am trying to do it :

IDL :

```
import "BindableBase.idl";
namespace WinrtApp2
{
    [bindable]
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        MainViewModel();
        String MyProperty;
    }
}
```

Header :

```
namespace winrt::WinrtApp2::implementation
{
    struct MainViewModel : MainViewModelT<MainViewModel>
    {
    public:
        static MainViewModel Instance();

    private:
        MainViewModel(){};
    };
}
```

Cpp:

```
MainViewModel MainViewModel::Instance()
{
 static MainViewModel instance = MainViewModel();
 return instance;
}
```

Compiler error :

```
WinrtApp2\Generated Files\winrt\base.h(7402,5): error C2248: 'winrt::WinrtApp2::implementation::MainViewModel::MainViewModel': cannot access private member declared in class 'winrt::WinrtApp2::implementation::MainViewModel'
WinrtApp2\MainViewModel.h(16): message : see declaration of 'winrt::WinrtApp2::implementation::MainViewModel::MainViewModel'
WinrtApp2\MainViewModel.h(9): message : see declaration of 'winrt::WinrtApp2::implementation::MainViewModel'
WinrtApp2\Generated Files\MainViewModel.g.cpp(10): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'auto winrt::make<winrt::WinrtApp2::implementation::MainViewModel,>(void)' being compiled
```

The c++/winrt documentation is very poor to understand/find something.

Comment: The [make](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/make) function template is trying to access `MainViewModel`'s private default constructor. Given the incomplete code and diagnostic message, I'm unable to see why the `make` function template is instantiated.

Comment: @IInspectable Please see the edit

Comment: That didn't add anything useful. I'm sure there's an IDL somewhere, and that you are using either the implementation type or projected type `MainViewModel`. The compiler isn't trying to instantiate either class template when it's not being used. Please show a [mcve], including the full error diagnostic.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes there is idl. In short the problem is when i am trying to make the constructor private the error occurs. But if the constructor is public there is no issue. To make the class single tone i am trying to just make the constructor private and a public getter to get the static instance.

Comment: The IDL is promising, that there is a publicly accessible default constructor. And still, the information provided is far from being a [mcve]. At any rate, does your singleton *have* to be a Windows Runtime type at all?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, it has to be a widows runtime library. My view models are going to be a c++/winrt library. I will share a git project. Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to model your view models as singletons, though? They usually store state that's only meaningful during the lifetime of the view they are attached to. Attaching the lifetime of a view model to the lifetime of the view that's using it seems like an obvious choice. Making the view model a class member of the view accomplishes that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a legitimate question and a common C++/CX pattern; I also hit when first learning C++/WinRT.

I think your issue is with scope, matching IInspectable's first comment. There are two types called MainViewModel:

1. `winrt::WinrtApp2::MainViewModel`
2. `winrt::WinrtApp2::implementation::MainViewModel`

The Instance() method should return type #1 but, as written, will return type #2. I would revise the Instance() method implementation to:

```
WinrtApp2::MainViewModel MainViewModel::Instance()
{
    static auto instance = WinrtApp2::MainViewModel();
    return instance;
}
```

and likewise change the header line to

```
static WinrtApp2::MainViewModel Instance();
```

Full (simplified) source:

Source.idl:

```
namespace winrtApp2
{
    [bindable]
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainViewModel
    {
        MainViewModel();
        String MyProperty;
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "MainViewModel.g.h"

namespace winrt::winrtApp2::implementation
{
    struct MainViewModel : MainViewModelT<MainViewModel>
    {
    public:
        static winrtApp2::MainViewModel Instance();
        winrt::hstring MyProperty() { return m_property; }
        void MyProperty(winrt::hstring val) {
            m_property = val;
        }

    private:
        MainViewModel() {};
        winrt::hstring m_property;
    };
}
```

MainViewModel.Cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainViewModel.h"

namespace winrt::winrtApp2::implementation {

winrtApp2::MainViewModel MainViewModel::Instance()
{
    static auto instance = winrtApp2::MainViewModel();
    return instance;
}
}
```

Comment: I have tried above solution but I am getting below error. 
Error C2280 'winrt::impl::heap_implements<D>::heap_implements(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function  XXXXXX XX\winrt\base.h 
Can you please let me know how to resolve this

Comment: I obviously don't have a way to get your error message. I've updated my solution above to include my full source. I did drop the original poster's unspecified BindableBase type, and implemented the MyProperty property.

Comment: I get below extra code in the generated MainViewModel.h file. Without below code there are errors:  Tried to use the same code thats in the answer for .idl,.cpp and in .h with extra code as below. still facing the same error as mentioned in first comment. 

namespace winrt::DeviceManager::factory_implementation
{
    struct MainViewModel : MainViewModelT<MainViewModel, implementation::MainViewModel>
    {
    };
}